# Laravel's "with" method returns empty list if I try to select single column

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

Here is my query:

```
User::with([
        'roles' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id AS value', 'display_name AS label');
        }
    ])->with([
        'followers' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'user_id');
        }
    ])->find($id);
```

This is what is executed in mysql:

```
select `id`, `user_id` from `followers` where 
`followers`.`followable_id` in (1) and `followers`.`followable_type` = 'user'
```

In mysql's console it returs results:

```
+----+---------+
| id | user_id |
+----+---------+
|  4 |       2 |
|  5 |       3 |
+----+---------+
```

In json response it is empty:

```
...
"followers": [],
...
```

If I omit this line

```
$query->select('id', 'user_id');
```

then json response contains

```
    ...
    "followers" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 4
      "followable_id" => 1
      "followable_type" => "user"
      "user_id" => 2
    ]
    1 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 5
      "followable_id" => 1
      "followable_type" => "user"
      "user_id" => 3
    ]
   ]
   ...
```

What I've tried:

1. $query->select('id', 'user_id');
2. $query->select('user_id');
3. $query->select('id', '*'); // this returns what is shown before

What I need: get list of users ids so that response would contain

```
...
"followers": [2, 3],
...
```

I know, i can do `foreach` after fetching it from database and modify result but why this one does not work?

Comment: try `return $query->select('id', 'user_id')`

Comment: Does not work. `with('roles')` works without return

Answer (score 1):

In `with()` function query use `addSelect` instaead select because when you use select other selection remove

try that hope it's help

Comment: The same works fine for `with(roles)`, without `return` statement, without `addSelect`.
Query in database is correct and it returns correct results.
There is some problem with Laravel's inner workings but I do not know where to search.

Answer (score 0):

Into your `with` method from your closures, you should return the Query instance.

Also, if the rendered MySQL query doesn't match what you expect so I think that there is an error with your relationships and/or your MySQL query.